# Sharepoint designer workflow copy

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

is it possible to copy **list** workflow developed in Sharepoint designer 2013 from one  site collection to another. I have to build on another site collection similar form library and it has the same worklow as one I developed earlier.

Is there a way to export to visio.. I have seen in posts that it can be done. But in my sharepoint designer that option is disabled (export to Visio is grayed out), and import option is enabled. I don't understand why?

BR

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a list workflow, but it is a bit of a hack.

http://www.sharepointbasic.com/2012/04/how-to-copy-sharepoint-list-workflow.html?m=1

This guide is for designer 2010, but it also works in designer 2013.

[Google Cache Version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Awww.sharepointbasic.com%2F2012%2F04%2Fhow-to-copy-sharepoint-list-workflow.html%3Fm%3D1&oq=cache%3Awww.sharepointbasic.com%2F2012%2F04%2Fhow-to-copy-sharepoint-list-workflow.html%3Fm%3D1&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1345j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Is it posible to use it in another site collection?

Comment: Is there a way to export to visio.. I have seen in posts that it can be done. But in my Sharepoint designer 2013 that option is disabled (export to Visio is grayed out),but import from Visio option is enabled. I don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to create a reusable workflow from designer, if you want to move to another site. Move/migrate a list and designer workflow to SharePoint 2013: http://expert-advice.org/sharepoint/migrate-list-sharepoint-designer-workflows-sharepoint-2010-sharepoint-2013/

Steps To Copy SharePoint Designer Workflow From One Site Collection To Another Site Collection: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/steps-to-copy-sharepoint-designer-workflow-from-one-site-col/

Comment: Hi :), thanks for answer. :) Workflow That i want to copy is list workflow, made over year ago. Now I have new list that needs to have same workflow but it is on another site collection. I want to copy workflow and attach it to the list. Also I have seen option export to visio but it is disabled. Do you know why? Because it is not reusable workflow?

Comment: No idea about Visio. I just know how to copy list workflows to reuse elsewhere (using the method in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I always use the next article: https://www.qdoscc.com/blog/how-copy-sharepoint-2013-workflows-one-site-collection-another

Though it has some drawbacks.
For example, it loses links to fields (since its IDs can change), so you need to reopen and check every action mentioning fields.

Also, after import and publish you need to close and reopen SP Designer to be able to change workflow start conditions.

Answer (score 0):

2010 Workflows could be migrated with some "hacks" with xml in packages. 2013 could not.

The only way I see is to try open two Sharepoint Designer instances, and drag-and-drop workflows from one SPD to another. Then restore links to lists inside workflow (giuds will be different)..

Best regards

Comment: The other ways is to use third-party tools like Sharegate, or to recreate 2013 workflow from scratch. I would also recommend to use Flow (Power Automate) instead of 2013 workflows